# Product images are not uploaded in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, image, varien-file-uploader

In magento admin while adding products image is not uploading.I tried by uploading in different browsers but it too doesn't worked.I have given 777 file permissions to media folder.When i upload image, image is stored in media/tmp/catalog/media folder.But it is not showing the image in the magento admin.Here is the screenshot of the issue.Can there be any reason for the image not saving in product in admin.[image]

Comment: Did you tried clearing browser's cache, or any other browser

Comment: Yes i tried clearing browser cache and also in other browser but image is not uploading.@TBIInfotech

Comment: Check if you have enough space at your FTP and if the limit was not exceeded.

Comment: Ok try logout and login, and check if the image is showing?

Comment: Image is saved in media/tmp/catalog/product folder.

Comment: Do you have adobe shockwave on your system?

Comment: When i run magento in localhost image is uploading correctly.

Comment: i have the same problem did you get the solution???

Comment: Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Same Problem in my website but i am using this code butt no working Please solved this problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136549)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136549)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable flash uploader magento and install the below plugin to solve the issue.
The Key for connect 2.0

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Dull_Uploader
```

Comment: could you please give some more detailed information on this plugin

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. The issue was with the PHP7.0.

I have such situation
[image: First]

I have chosen the image, have clicked the "Upload" button.
The row with the file name has become in red color.

I have debuged it and found error

Then I have fixed it quickly
[image: I have added the {} symbols and Uploading starts working]

Comment: Yes, It's working

Comment: the change in code saved my life! was looking for hours until i stumbled upon this answer

Comment: @xdoctordog sorry i dont get what u r suggesting on that line . Can u plz explain it

Comment: Please, try to add braces in core Magento file, like I had shown on the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

**Product images are not uploaded in magento admin**

1. Make Sure u have uploaded flash player
2. Enable GD library in the `php.ini` file -> `;extension=php_gd2.dll` Remove `;`

Answer (score 0):

Give 777 permission to this folder :
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/media/wysiwyg

Answer (score -2):

Goto FTP open Media Directory and just change name of

> .htaccess to .htaccess_old

And remove the Cache

Comment: Never use this solution. You may face other issue to. Because .htaccess files are used for setting up site configuration and  renaming current one will overwrite setting and a default one will be created.

Comment: When you do this, you open yourself up to people uploading php scripts into your media directory structure and being able to execute them. Congratulations for opening up a security hole that the Titanic can pass through. If you read that .htaccess file, it has specific entries to prevent execution of files out of the media folders.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me (on an older version of Magento of 1.3.2.4) was a recursive permission of 777 of the media folder AND renaming the .htaccess to .htaccessold - I then logged out, cleared the cache, logged back in and IT WORKED!!

Comment: The removed .htaccess file had specific entries to prevent file execution out of the media folder structure. You've just enabled a security hole.