# Magento 1.9 and php7.0 - image upload error File was not uploaded

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

[image: Magento 1.9 and php7.0 - image upload error File was not uploaded]

Hello,
We have face issue in admin area. "Showing error File was not uploaded"

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93066/magento-1-9-2-and-php7-image-upload-error

Comment: Already  this line in Uploader.php . Line number 274                 
 $params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);

Comment: can you confirm that you applied the Magento patch for PHP7 support?

Answer (score 0):

Open

> lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

and make this change https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uVeh.jpg .

source info from [error php 7.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/product-images-are-not-uploaded-in-magento-admin)

Option 2 . 
Patch SUPEE-7405 made changes on permissions files .

> Upload File Permissions
>
> The patch restores less restrictive file permissions (0666 for files
>   and 0777 for directories) as more strict permissions introduced by the
>   original SUPEE-7405 patch caused many merchants not to be able to view
>   uploaded product images, depending on hosting provider configuration.

To fix that: on this file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

change this `chmod($destinationFile, 0640)` to `chmod($destinationFile, 0644)`

Comment: Already exist this changes.                                                                                                                                             `//run validate callbacks
        foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
            if (is_object($params['object']) && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])) {
                $params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
            }
        }`

Comment: updated my answer please check.

Comment: We have already changed this chmod($destinationFile, 0640) to chmod($destinationFile, 0644)   . but still showing error

Comment: Please provide a solution for this problem.

Comment: add the permissions following Mathew answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957448/chmod-640-for-uploaded-file-after-supee-7405-patch